# How can I properly determine if a page reload should be via ajax when using history in rails?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, history.js

I am using rails 3.2 with datatables, bootstrap, and jquery, a combination that seems to make pjax, history.js, turbolinks, bbq, etc, all not work, or at least not work the way I want it to.  I want to be able to navigate through dashboard reports via forward and back buttons.  The system I have so far works in Chrome (version 27 according to my about box).

I have a series of buttons that each load the dashboard reports via ajax using this binding in my index.js.erb:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.updates_history').bind('ajax:before', function(){
      history.pushState(<%= params.to_json.html_safe %>,
        this.textContext,
        this.href);
    });
  });
```

I can then pop the state using this script in my index.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $('document').ready(function(){
    //When 'next' or 'before' is clicked
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      $.ajax( { url:document.location } );
    };
});
</script>
```

The `respond_to` block in my dashboards_controller.rb looks like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
  format.json {render json: Datatable.new(view_context)}
  end
end
```

And this works fine, except if I go to history prior to visiting the site.  So I start with an about:blank page, and then enter the localhost:3000/dashboards url, and then navigate around.  If I hit back all the way prior to navigating to the dashboards page, and then I hit forward, the only page that loads is the index.js.erb, and it's not compiled.  I suspect that that's because I'm just calling `$.ajax( { url:document.location } );` to pop the history state.  What should I be doing on that line to make everything behave nicely, ie, not require a full page load when bouncing around between reports, but require a full page load when returning to the aegis of the controller?